# Unable to send UTF-8 encoded string from Android to Node.js

Tags: node.js, utf-8, mqtt

I'm trying to make a simple messaging app. I've encoded the strings in UTF-8 in Android through the provided methods:

```
String msg = "helloo";
byte[] bytemsg = msg.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I'm sending this through MQTT (Paho library) to my server where I receive it using mosca library.

```
var received = new Buffer(payload).toString('utf8');
```

However, I'm not receiving what I sent. In the above example, I get ��� Also, when I send "hello", nothing gets displayed.

I read about javascript's problem with utf-8 characters, but I'm not using characters beyond the basic plane. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: why you convert string to bytemsg, before sending through mqtt

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, I've tried it both ways. Just thought I'd be clearer as to what I'm doing.

Comment: use packet.payload instead of payload

Answer (score 3):

Get UTF-8 string from array of bytes

```
var buff = new Buffer(bytes);
console.log(buff.toString('utf8'));
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. It's pretty much what I'm doing. Any other ideas?